# Verb normalization of こだわらなさ

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I'm confused about how I should parse こだわらなさすぎだ in this sentence.

> お前は １つの問題に こだわらなさすぎだ 最後まで諦めんなよ

From the context of the show I was watching, I'm pretty sure that this means "You focus too much on one problem (on a test). Don't give up until the end."

I thought that こだわらなさすぎ would mean "not fixated enough (on a problem)" since こだわりすぎ means "to be fixated too much".

Is there a difference between saying こだわらなさすぎ vs こだわりすぎ?

Comment: こだわらなすぎる is the canonical form, but こだわらなさすぎる is becoming more and more common.

Comment: こだわりすぎ is in the positive, lacking the negation found in こだわらなさすぎ

Comment: Ah, right, the translation is not "You focus too much on one problem" but "You are too **un**focused on each one of the problems".